# How to increment shared_ptr in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, stl, shared-ptr

I get shared_ptr from the function. Shared ptr points to a big array of bytes. I want to return this shared_ptr but point it to the 16th byte in this array.
Example with raw pointers (working):

```
uint8_t* SomeFunction() {
  uint8_t* array = SomeOtherFunction();
  return array + 16;
}
```

Example with shared pointers (doesn't working):

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> SomeFunction() {
  std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> array = SomeOtherFunction();
  return array + 16;
}
```

I don't want to reallocate the array because it's big and reallocation needs time.
I want to return the same shared ptr, but that its `get()` method would return the `raw pointer` + 16. But deallocation memory at the original pointer address.

Can I do it? How?

Comment: The first function is fundamentally flawed, you can't delete the pointer, unless you rewind the pointer back by 16. But if you have that information anyway (how much to rewind) you don't need to return the shifted pointer.

Comment: Can't be done easily. You would need a custom deleter to delete the pointer 16 bytes before the held pointer. But that would change the type of the smart pointer. So basically impossible.

Comment: @john `std::shared_ptr` elides the deleter type. It does not require a custom pointer type. You might be thinking of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was thinking of `unique_ptr`, not sure how I managed to misread the question.

Comment: How are the new '+16' pointer and the original pointer going to cooperate on deleting the raw pointer?

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliasing constructor might be used:

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> SomeFunction() {
  std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> array = SomeOtherFunction();
  return {array, array.get() + 16};
}
```

Comment: Perfect: Learn something new everyday. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr See constructor 8 (requires c++20)

Comment: @Martin York: only 8bis (the one taking rvalue `shared_ptr`) is C++20, the one taking const reference is C++11.